# Триггер события scroll

Tags: javascript

Как вызвать событие `scroll` на чистом `javascript` без использования сторонних библиотек.

К примеру я могу вызвать такое событие как `click()` у элементов, и из-за этого сработает триггер на клик у этого элемента. Так же с событиями `.focus()` и `.blur()`.

Как сделать тоже самое (похожее) на `scroll`.

---

Пробовал присваивать у скроллируемого элемента значение `scrollTop` сначала на `+1`, и сразу же на `-1`, это сработало, но я считаю это грязным вариантом.

Comment: опишите точнее что именно и куда хотите прокрутить?

Comment: @Grundy ничего и никуда, просто запустить триггер скролла. Чтобы все подписанты выполнили свой метод

Comment: А если присвоить текущее значение без +1 и -1, разве не сработает?

Comment: @sivik_xes увы нет. Пробовал. Должно явно изменится значение. Но к примеру если ты вызовешь событие `.change()` у поля это не значит, что в нем изменилось значение.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для вызова событий на любых элементах нужно использовать объект `Event`

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Рабочий ответ:

```
var scroll = document.getElementById('scrollBlock');
scroll.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

Для IE нужно читать спецификацию о поддержке вызовов `Event` у элементов `DOM` модели

Answer (score 0):

Для создания событий можно использовать конструкторы. В частности для события прокрутки [UIEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/UIEvent)

```
var scrollEvent = new UIEvent('scroll');
```

Для вызова созданного события используется функция [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```
element.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent);
```

[Пример создания и вызова событий на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)